# Return Iterator Method

Tags: c#, iterator

Let `FirstMethod` be defined to be an iterator method. Let `SecondMethod` be defined to invoke `FirstMethod`, but return the result directly rather than `foreach`ing over it and `yield`ing its items. If `ThirdMethod` iterates over the result of `SecondMethod`, is the entire chain treated as an iteration, or to achieve such must I `yield` inside of `SecondMethod`?

e.g.

```
IEnumerable<string> FirstMethod()
{
  yield return "one";
  yield return "two";
  yield return "three";
}

IEnumerable<string> SecondMethod()
{
  return FirstMethod();
}

IEnumerable<string> ThirdMethod()
{
  foreach (string item in SecondMethod())
  {
    yield return item;
  }
}

void Main()
{
  foreach (string item in ThirdMethod())
  {
    Console.WriteLine(item);
  }
}
```

I realize that I will still get all of the items to display in this example. My concern, however, is to preserve the "lazy" evaluation of the iterators until `Main`.

Comment: You could have added a few `Console.WriteLine()` calls into your example here and answered this for yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will remain lazy. You're returning an `IEnumerable<T>` which does not materialize the result until it's enumerated.

Your code will behave in exactly the same way as if you were to omit `SecondMethod` and call `FirstMethod` from `ThirdMethod`.

You can actually test this by dropping logging statements within `FirstMethod`

```
IEnumerable<string> FirstMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Returning one");
    yield return "one";
    Console.WriteLine("Returning two");
    yield return "two";
    Console.WriteLine("Returning three");
    yield return "three";
}
```

Now, with your debugger, put a breakpoint within `SecondMethod`. Note that nothing is printed *until* we begin iterating over `SecondMethod()`. Here's what the output would look like:

```
Returning one
one
Returning two
two
Returning three
three
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand how it works, you can simply place breakpoints and debug it.
Another way is to add some debug output points:

```
IEnumerable<string> FirstMethod()
{
  Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod start.");
  Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod: one");
  yield return "one";
  Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod: two");
  yield return "two";
  Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod: three");
  yield return "three";
  Console.WriteLine("FirstMethod end.");
}

IEnumerable<string> SecondMethod()
{
  Console.WriteLine("SecondMethod start.");
  return FirstMethod();
}

IEnumerable<string> ThirdMethod()
{
  Console.WriteLine("ThirdMethod start.");
  foreach (string item in SecondMethod())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("ThirdMethod: " + item);
    yield return item;
  }
  Console.WriteLine("ThirdMethod end.");
}

void Main()
{
  foreach (string item in ThirdMethod())
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Main: " + item);
  }
}
```

This code results into the following call order:

```
ThirdMethod start.
SecondMethod start.
FirstMethod start.
FirstMethod: one
ThirdMethod: one
Main: one
FirstMethod: two
ThirdMethod: two
Main: two
FirstMethod: three
ThirdMethod: three
Main: three
FirstMethod end.
ThirdMethod end.
```

If we remove `foreach` from `Main`, then we get empty output.

So, yes, "lazy" evaluation is preserved, i.e. `SecondMethod` just returns an `IEnumerable` and values are being enumerated after call in `Main`.

That's exactly how LINQ preserves this behavior while chaining LINQ methods and enumerates only when you call `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()` etc. or use `foreach`.